# Is it possible to run java (jdk-windows) , Eclipse (indigo) and Android-sdk FOR android app development from external flash drive

Tags: java, android, eclipse

im wondering if we can develop our android app in any computer we use by holding the requirments software for that on external flash drive , which i mean to install the java , eclipse and android sdk on flash drive , so finally we can carry flash to any computer and develope android app in any compute even that computers doesnt has installed that softwares needed , really i searched alot in internet and try alot of suggestion one of them :

i download portable java from(portableapps.com)and portable eclipse from (sourceforge.net), but it doesnt work .

any adviced ideas will be appreciated ,

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i get the solution which is work fine to me as follow:

1-download the java software then install it on my PC with install path to flash driver.

2-download android SDK then install it on pc with install path to flash driver .

3-download Eclipse unzipped it on predetermined folder on flash drive , then create folder inside Eclipse folder and call it ( jre ) , then go to program files on Pc and copy java folder then past it in JRE folder in Eclipse folder .

4-FINALLY run Eclipse , it will work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but in the `eclipse.ini` you have to specify the JVM to use, and select the JVM on the flash drive.

Look at this [page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: ill check it ,im trying some thing now may i will reach to my target, thanks