# Can't Specify targetSDKVersion for Android With EclipsePortable

Tags: java, android

I am Trying to create a basic hello world android app. The problem is that when I make a new android project and try to specify the targetSDKVersion the choose button is unclickable and can't press the down arrow.

The linked image shows some info as to where the SDK Location is and how I cannot specify the target http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/196/newandroidproject.jpg/

I have Eclipse Portable installed on a portable flash drive, with Java installed and Android 4.1 installed and the ADT plugin in stalled.

The Flash Drive is K: In K: Inside is 1.) Eclipse  Portable and 2.) Android
Inside Eclipse Portable 
.
In K:\EclipsePortable

```
6/11/2012  02:06 PM    <DIR>          .
6/11/2012  02:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
6/11/2012  02:06 PM    <DIR>          App
1/24/2011  07:09 PM            69,941 EclipsePortable.
1/24/2011  07:56 PM             4,745 help.html
6/11/2012  02:09 PM    <DIR>          Other
6/11/2012  02:09 PM    <DIR>          Data
6/11/2012  02:49 PM    <DIR>          JDK
6/11/2012  02:54 PM    <DIR>          JRE
6/11/2012  03:06 PM    <DIR>          javafx
6/21/2012  01:45 PM            21,910 hs_err_pid1848.l
6/22/2012  02:55 PM            22,769 hs_err_pid3476.l
```

Inside K:\Android

```
06/27/2012  07:14 PM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2012  07:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/24/2012  01:53 PM           357,814 AVD Manager.exe
06/24/2012  01:53 PM           357,814 SDK Manager.exe
06/24/2012  01:53 PM             1,170 SDK Readme.txt
06/27/2012  07:14 PM    <DIR>          add-ons
06/27/2012  07:14 PM    <DIR>          platforms
06/27/2012  07:14 PM    <DIR>          tools
06/27/2012  07:15 PM            70,987 uninstall.exe
06/28/2012  02:35 PM    <DIR>          temp
06/28/2012  02:36 PM    <DIR>          platform-tools
06/30/2012  09:32 PM    <DIR>          docs
06/30/2012  11:13 PM    <DIR>          samples
06/30/2012  11:17 PM    <DIR>          sources
06/30/2012  11:52 PM    <DIR>          system-images
           4 File(s)        787,785 bytes
          11 Dir(s)   1,719,787,520 bytes free
```

Inside platforms is Android-16 and inside that is template, skins and data and an android.jar file.

Should I follow the user [Android Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278943/android-stack)'s answer [mentioned in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055614/is-it-possible-to-run-java-jdk-windows-eclipse-indigo-and-android-sdk-for) . And the person asking the question used portable java but the user 'Android Stack' said to copy regular java from `C:\Program Files\...` Which one is needed?

P.S. Someone told me that this directory setup for Android is weird. Is this so? If so, I might need to give some more info.

Comment: Could someone please assist me?

Comment: Can you just skip it and define it in the manifest with android:targetSDKversion, or does it require one to create the project?

Comment: When I tried to see by opening eclipse, it said Android SDK Verification
Could not find SDK folder "K:\Android\". I tried to read the the Android SDK Location ( which is now L:\Android ) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still your Sdk setup for android is not complete so please add Android proper sdk location from windows->preference. And select Android or you may check your android plugin.

Comment: When I Opened Eclipse, it said, "Could not find SDK folder K:\Android\." I tried to read the the Android SDK Location ( which is now L:\Android ), and it worked. Thanks