# how to avoid dependency on system jdk and run the java program on windows

Tags: java, maven

I have build maven java program module. used maven assembly to build the below structure.

folder structure

bin
lib
logs
data

bin contains .bat file from where we call the application (main.java file) like below. lib contains all jars in the module.

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -classpath "%APPCLASSPATH%" "-Dconfig.file=%CONFIG%" "-Dlog.file=%LOGFILE%" com.xx.App
```

problem:

if there is no java 1.6 on this matchine, I am not able to run the .bat file on windows. if I manually set the PATH variable to java bin folder, it is working.

please let me know how to make sure my maven java module works without having the java installed on the machine from which the .bat file being executed.

below is my .bat file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM Run Data Migration 
REM It initiates Data Migration


if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto nt
echo This script only works with NT-based versions of Windows.
goto :end

:nt
rem
rem Find the application home.
rem
rem %~dp0 is location of current script under NT
set CURRMath=%~dp0
set APPCLASSMath=%CURRMath%/../lib/MathVerifierBatch.jar
set CONFIG=%CURRMath%/../config/metogenverfier.properties
set LOGFILE=%CURRMath%/../logs/metogenMathveri.log
set REPORTFILE=%CURRMath%/../report/
set data.file.Math=%CURRMath%/../data/mata_getogenconfig.xml
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -classMath "%APPCLASSMath%" "-Dconfig.file=%CONFIG%" "-Dlog.file=%LOGFILE%" "-Ddataload.file=%LOADFILE%" com.cts.mms.process.main.App
```

Comment: how could you run java if java is not installed? I don't understand the question

Comment: we can set the class path to jars(may need to include jdk) in the lib folder in .bat file before actually calling the App.

Comment: Are you asking if the JDK can be run from a flash-drive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055614/is-it-possible-to-run-java-jdk-windows-eclipse-indigo-and-android-sdk-for

Comment: No i am not using flash drive.